# Set App delegate as first responder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, shake, becomefirstresponder

I'm trying to implement a shake recognition that works throughout my application. To do this I'm adding the following code to my xxxAppDelegate.m:

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        NSLog(@"Shaken, not stirred.");
    }
}
```

But because in the .h file the delegate is defined as a

```
@interface xxxAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

I cannot use the

```
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

in the .m to make the app delegate the first responder. Therefore of course it doesn't work.
What would be the best way to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you change the app delegate to a subclass of `UIResponder`?

### Edit

You can read about the responder chain [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html) in the documentation.